# How fast would you have to go in space to be warmed to a comfortable temperature?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmic-microwave-background, space, redshift

How fast would you have to go in space, not near a star, such that the Cosmic Microwave Background is blueshifted enough to warm you to a comfortable temperature (70 F or 21.111 C)?  Expressing it in terms of the speed of light - e.g. .99 C might be the most helpful.

Comment: A follow on thought, it seems this would be about the fastest a spacecraft carrying people could go - unless cooling is provided.

Answer (score 0):

First, moving in space would not result simply in a thermal spectrum with a different temperature. Second, how much the radiation warms you depends on your insulation and in particular on how much heat you radiate. (side note, vacuum is an excellent insulator). So to answer the question one need to specify the interface to the environment (bare skin, space suit, tin foil, thermal ceramics, etc), the surface to volume ratio and whether there are other heat sources (humane bodies, engines, etc.)

Comment: The cosmic microwave background is about 4 degrees Kelvin, so if we are going very near the speed of light, it should be blueshifted and be hotter in the direction of motion.  My question is, how fast would that be (e.g. .99 C) to shift that to where it would keep us comfortably warm?